# ORA-22835: Buffer too small and ORA-25137: Data value out of range

Tags: database, oracle

We are using a software that has limited Oracle capabilities. I need to filter through a CLOB field by making sure it has a specific value. Normally, outside of this software I would do something like:

```sql
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(t.new_value) = 'Y'
```

However, this isn't supported so I'm attempting to use `CAST` instead. I've tried many different attempts but so far these are what I found:

The software has a built-in query checker/validator and these are the ones it shows as invalid:

```sql
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(t.new_value)
CAST(t.new_value AS VARCHAR2(10))
CAST(t.new_value AS NVARCHAR2(10))
```

However, the validator does accept these:

```sql
CAST(t.new_value AS VARCHAR(10))
CAST(t.new_value AS NVARCHAR(10))
CAST(t.new_value AS CHAR(10))
```

Unfortunately, even though the validator lets these ones go through, when running the query to fetch data, I get `ORA-22835: Buffer too small` when using `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`. And I get `ORA-25137: Data value out of range` when using `CHAR`.

Are there other ways I could try to check that my CLOB field has a specific value when filtering the data? If not, how do I fix my current issues?

Comment: How long is `new_value`?  It seems odd to declare a column as a `clob` and then only store a single character in it.  The errors you're getting imply that the values stored are more than 10 characters/ bytes long.  Are they potentially more than 32k?

Comment: @JustinCave The `new_value` tracks changes to a field value so it is an arbitrary length. It also tracks changes to `TEXT` fields which might contain lots and lots of characters. But for what I'm needing it now, is just a single text, either `N` or `Y`.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a `text` data type.  The errors imply that the values you're looking at are more than 10 characters.  Depending on what the software is doing, it is possible that your `cast` is being applied before whatever other predicates you have that are reducing the rows you're interested in to just those with a single character of data.  I don't know if the software gives you the ability to control that but I would tend to doubt it if it won't even let you use built-in packages.  Does it allow `instr` or `substr`?

Comment: @JustinCave sorry yes, Oracle doesn't have `TEXT` - I keep mixing Oracle and MySQL. Also, the query validator doesn't recognize `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`.

Comment: @JustinCave what you said about `CAST` being applied **before** reducing the rows to what I'm only interested in seems to be the issue here. I had to create a subquery to filter the rows and only get rows that I know will only contain one character. Then I did the `CAST` **after**. If you put that in as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates that Oracle is trying to apply the `CAST(t.new_value AS VARCHAR(10))` to a row where `new_value` has more than 10 characters.  That makes sense given your description that `new_value` is a generic audit field that has values from a large number of different tables with a variety of data lengths.  Given that, you'd need to structure the query in a way that forces the optimizer to reduce the set of rows you're applying the `cast` to down to just those where `new_value` has just a single character before applying the `cast`.

Not knowing what sort of scope the software you're using provides for structuring your code, I'm not sure what options you have there.  Be aware that depending on how robust you need this, the optimizer has quite a bit of flexibility to choose to apply predicates and functions on the projection in an arbitrary order.  So even if you find an approach that works once, it may stop working in the future when statistics change or the database is upgraded and Oracle decides to choose a different plan.

Answer (score 0):

Using this as sample data

```
create table tab1(col clob);
insert into tab1(col) values (rpad('x',3000,'y'));
```

You need to use `dbms_lob.substr(col,1)` to get the *first* character (from the default `offset`= 1)

```
select dbms_lob.substr(col,1) from tab1;

DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(COL,1)
----------------------
x
```

Note that the [default `amount`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349) (= length) of the substring is `32767` so using only `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(COL)`  will return more than you expects.

`CAST` for `CLOB` does **not** *cut* the string to the casted length, but (as you observes) returns the exception `ORA-25137: Data value out of range`  if the original string is longert that the casted length.

As documented for the [`CAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75) statement

> CAST does not directly support any of the LOB data types. When you use CAST to convert a CLOB value into a character data type or a BLOB value into the RAW data type, the database implicitly converts the LOB value to character or raw data and then explicitly casts the resulting value into the target data type. *If the resulting value is larger than the target type, then the database returns an error.*

Comment: Unfortunately even after adding the offset, the query validator doesn't recognize `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR()` so I can't use that. I thought `CAST` is able to cut the string because we also had to use a workaround for `TRUNC`: `CAST(CAST(date_field AS VARCHAR(9)) AS DATE)` and it works. It gets rid of the time portion. I was hoping we could do something similar for this one.

Comment: Yes this works for `VARCHAR` but unfortunatelly not for `CLOB` I updated the answer. @PatrickGregorio